# Cloudformation Custom Resource Orchestration/precedence?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, orchestration

I have a Cloudformation Custom Resource, that I want to use the outputs from, and call another Custom Resource.

I tried exporting the Outputs, and tinkered with using DependsOn, hoping it would set some order of precedence.

Is this Possible:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Run Lambda1, then run Lambda2 w/ outpu from Lambda1
Outputs:
      lambda1Output:
        Value:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - lambda1
          - test
        Export:
            Name: lambda1Outputs
Resources:
  lambda1:
    Type: Custom::test
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:761861444952:function:runOnce
  lambda2:
    Type: Custom::test2
    DependsOn: lambda1
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:761861444952:function:runOnce
      myParameter: !ImportValue lambda1Outputs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easier way to achieve what you want.

```
Resources:
  lambda1:
    Type: Custom::test
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:761861444952:function:runOnce
  lambda2:
    Type: Custom::test2
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:761861444952:function:runOnce
      myParameter: !GetAtt lambda1.test
```

So no need for the `Outputs` block or `DependsOn`. The CloudFormation dependency engine will understand that lambda1 needs to be executed before lambda2.

Comment: Worked ! Thx much. Learning this YAML stuff